# How to interpret image uploaded through form (POST) instead of local image Python PIL

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to interpret an image and my code works for interpreting the image saved locally but I want to interpret the image that I upload to a form through POST without actually storing it locally. Is that possible?

1. I tried to use `request.form['receipt-photo']` (`receipt-photo` is the name of the upload field)

```
text = image_to_string(Image.open(request.form['receipt-photo']))
```

but I got `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'receipt3.jpg'`

2. I also tried

```
text = image_to_string(request.form['receipt-photo'])
```

Error I got.

`pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.0.0 with Leptonica Error, cannot read input file /Users/alexmarginean/Documents/Projects/Weeper/receipt3.jpg: No such file or directory Error during processing.')`

3. Then I searched online and I found something about converting to bytes but it didn't work for me

```
text = image_to_string(Image.open(BytesIO(request.form['receipt-photo'])))
```

Error I got: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

---

## This works (but it uses the locally stored image)

This was my code that was using the locally stored image

```
text = image_to_string(Image.open('receipt3.jpg'))
```

I expect my photo to be usable just from sending a POST request without saving the image locally.
I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder where you want to store the uploaded files, let's call it `/uploads`

In your form create an upload field and button

```
<form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="receipt-photo">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Then in Flask (assuming you use flask) add an endpoint

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=[POST])
    file = request.files['receipt-photo']
    f = os.path.join('/uploads', file.filename)

    file.save(f)

    # Manipulate image with PIL
```

Comment: I tried this and for some reason the image doesn't get saved into the `/uploads` directory, and so I get this error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/uploads/receipt3.jpg'`